# Message gets weird from: Service bus/BrokeredMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

When I send a guid as message and receive it, the message become weird:

> @guid3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�$ed92ba5c-68ed-2a4c-8d89-0a087e47ef11

Any idea why I do not only get Guid as message?

Sender:

```
 public void Post(Guid id) {
            var connectionString = "X";
            var queueName = "Send";

            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            var message = new BrokeredMessage(id);    

            client.Send(message);                  
        }
```

Receiver:

```
  public string ReadPost() {
            var connectionString = "X";
            var queueName = "Send";

            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            var message = client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            var stream = message?.GetBody<Stream>();
            if (stream == null) { return null; }

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var textFromBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

            message.Complete();

            return textFromBody;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
message.GetBody<Guid>();
```

instead of getting the stream.

Service Bus queues use DataContractSerializer to serialize the message body, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, can I remove `reader` and `textFromBody` and return Guid instead from: `var getGuid = message?.GetBody<Guid>();` safetly? First time I'm using Service Bus. EDIT: What I ask if StreamReader function is essential to keep or not for my purpose.

Comment: Yeah you don't need those two. You already have the Guid from GetBody. Don't forget to Complete the message though once you have processed the message successfully so it doesn't come up again.